# Rails 5: Slow server response time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I am having some issues with a new website I'm building and deploying to Heroku.  My logs say:

```
Completed 200 OK in 2356ms (Views: 239.0ms | ActiveRecord: 8.2ms)
```

but my chrome developer tools show a response time of ~4 seconds.  When I analyze with the Heroku Scout add-on, it shows that 90% of the time is spent in the controller, but the page I'm loading is the homepage, with nearly no database queries and all static assets are cached.

Any idea what I should try next?

Comment: maybe you have a lot of javascript code doing things in frontend?

Comment: hmm.. not really.  And wouldn't that go against the whole "90% of time spent in the controller"?

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw the part about the controller, but it says that the request was completed in 2356ms in the backend, the browser with ~4 seconds, have to be on the frontend those 2 other seconds right? About the controller, maybe some callabacks? some gem that is doing/checking something in every request?